# Injecting dependencies in unit tests in Angular 2 2.0.0-rc.5

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, dependency-injection

Are there any instructions or example set ups for how to inject dependencies in Angular 2, latest release?

[The Testing Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) is still incomplete, and only takes you so far. If, for example, you want to test a component that takes `@Input()` parameters, my understanding is that you specifically need to inject it, but I've run into some problems getting this to work.

When I try to follow examples such as [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8d746e3f6795c8840116f4649a37a1efb4243eb9/modules/%40angular/compiler/test/directive_normalizer_spec.ts) I get errors about `configureCompiler` not being a part of `@angular/core/testing`. I believe this [may have been moved into TestBed](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a86c554a8e24fb2a60858d7acb8538ae7851bdc2/modules/%40angular/core/testing/test_component_builder.ts#L23) but when I try to use call `TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)` I get an error that there's `No provider for TestingCompilerFactory!` And when I try to import it from [`@angular/compiler/testing`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b96869afd2bdd3ad8c5b7477da647af628e383aa/modules/%40angular/compiler/testing.ts#L25) I get a Typescript compiler error that it isn't there. Doing a grep, I can find the file it's in in my local `node_nodiles` but then that file gives a bunch of Typescript errors if I try to import it!

Is there any straightforward guide on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Getting testing in RC5 can be difficult as it's still so new. You can look at this angular2-starter (https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular2-starter) and see how he has implemented testing in RC5.

Comment: And another example here that is slightly more concise: https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed/blob/master/src/test/greeting-component_test.ts